# Can I use a proxy to secure elasticsearch?

Tags: linux, nginx, security, proxy, authentication

I have deployed an open source public web service (elasticsearch) on Ubuntu. Problem is - no security at all (only if you pay).

I've researched a bit about blocking ports only to internal requests while allowing external access only through authentication proxy.

The simplest way was nginx with basic authentication.

But what's the best practice in those cases? What are my other options?

Answer (score 0):

The official security plugin for it is https://www.elastic.co/products/shield.  It offers encryption as well as password authentication, and best practice usually dictates that in a professional environment you buy that from them.

However, lots of people use proxies to authenticate access, and this is fine too as long as your network segmentation has absolutely nothing but that proxy able to communicate with elasticsearch.

Take a look at this stack overflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956062/authentication-in-elasticsearch.